# Apply style with selectors css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this structure :

```
<div class="primero">
    <div>
        <div>hola</div>
        <div>hola2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How i can to apply style to the div with the content "hola2", but using css´selectors ?

thank

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
.primero div div:last-child {
    /*your style here*/
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
.primero div:nth-child(2) {
    /* style here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested style will help you do this, although this code is kinda sloppy... Please make sure it won't affect other style in you document.

```
.primero > div > div:nth-child(2){your style}
```